# Ubuntu Cannot change permissions on files I own and have RW to

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.10, file-permissions, chmod

I have a harddrive full of backups which for me is mounted at /media/chronus_
I have been trying to give another user rw permission to this drive.

The problem is that I cannot change any permissions on this drive, even if i make a new file it puts sets everything to -rw-------
here is an excerpt of what i have tried:

```
madmaze@the-gibson:~$ touch testfile
madmaze@the-gibson:~$ ls -l testfile 
-rw-r--r-- 1 madmaze madmaze 0 2011-01-16 20:11 testfile
madmaze@the-gibson:~$ chmod 777 testfile 
madmaze@the-gibson:~$ ls -l testfile 
-rwxrwxrwx 1 madmaze madmaze 0 2011-01-16 20:11 testfile
madmaze@the-gibson:~$ cd /media/chronos_/Pix/
madmaze@the-gibson:/media/chronos_/Pix$ ls -l
total 4100
-rw------- 1 madmaze madmaze   28226 2011-01-16 20:18 avp.jpg
-rw------- 1 madmaze madmaze    5764 2011-01-16 20:18 avpsmall.jpg
-rw------- 1 madmaze madmaze   98414 2011-01-16 20:18 john.jpg
-rw------- 1 madmaze madmaze   98785 2011-01-16 20:18 lisa.jpg
-rw------- 1 madmaze madmaze 3954281 2011-01-16 20:18 peter.jpg
madmaze@the-gibson:/media/chronos_/Pix$ chmod 777 *.jpg
madmaze@the-gibson:/media/chronos_/Pix$ ls -l
total 4100
-rw------- 1 madmaze madmaze   28226 2011-01-16 20:18 avp.jpg
-rw------- 1 madmaze madmaze    5764 2011-01-16 20:18 avpsmall.jpg
-rw------- 1 madmaze madmaze   98414 2011-01-16 20:18 john.jpg
-rw------- 1 madmaze madmaze   98785 2011-01-16 20:18 lisa.jpg
-rw------- 1 madmaze madmaze 3954281 2011-01-16 20:18 peter.jpg
madmaze@the-gibson:/media/chronos_/Pix$ sudo chmod 777 *.jpg
madmaze@the-gibson:/media/chronos_/Pix$ ls -l
total 4100
-rw------- 1 madmaze madmaze   28226 2011-01-16 20:18 avp.jpg
-rw------- 1 madmaze madmaze    5764 2011-01-16 20:18 avpsmall.jpg
-rw------- 1 madmaze madmaze   98414 2011-01-16 20:18 john.jpg
-rw------- 1 madmaze madmaze   98785 2011-01-16 20:18 lisa.jpg
-rw------- 1 madmaze madmaze 3954281 2011-01-16 20:18 peter.jpg
madmaze@the-gibson:/media/chronos_/Pix$ touch testfile
madmaze@the-gibson:/media/chronos_/Pix$ ls -l testfile 
-rw------- 1 madmaze madmaze 0 2011-01-16 20:25 testfile
madmaze@the-gibson:/media/chronos_/Pix$ chmod 777 testfile
madmaze@the-gibson:/media/chronos_/Pix$ ls -l testfile 
-rw------- 1 madmaze madmaze 0 2011-01-16 20:25 testfile
madmaze@the-gibson:/media/chronos_/Pix$
```

Any Ideas what I could be doing wrongly?
The Filesystem is NTFS

Is it possible that NTFS doesnt support other permissions?

Comment: What filesystem is the drive - FAT, NTFS, ext3, etc.?

Comment: arg, i thought it was ext3 but its NTFS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible that NTFS doesnt
>   support other permissions?

Yes. The NTFS driver included in Ubuntu (NTFS 3G) doesn't support ownership and rights changes. From [Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions):

> The present limitations of this driver
>   are:
>
> - writing files encrypted or compressed at the filesystem level (does not include .zip, .gz, .rar
>     files since they are compressed on the
>     file, not the file system level)
> - changing NTFS file ownership and access rights

Answer (score 0):

You can change the permissions of your mount files with something like

`mount -t ntfs -o umask=022,uid=madmaze,gid=madmaze /dev/sdb1 /media/chronus`

where umask=022 gives 644 (-rw-r--r--) for file permissions, and 755 (drwxr-xr-x) for directory permissions.